# How to change default text color for entire site

Tags: css

I built a website with a WYSIWYG website builder using a template provided by the program.  I have since abandoned the template and use CSS to style everything, but for some reason I cannot change the default text color of the whole site.

I thought that simply changing the body color in the CSS would change the default color:

```
body {
font-family: Lato;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.42857143;
color: #ff9900;
background-color: #750204;
```

So I tried changing the color: #ff9900 to "b6b6b6" but that didn't work.

Then I literally replaced *every* instance of ff9900 in the CSS file to b6b6b6 and still the website shows the color ff9900.  I don't get how that's possible.

Obviously I don't really know what I'm doing so be gentle.  Thanks for any advice.

EDIT:  here is what I see when I inspect the live page:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using *DevTools (F12)* on your live website in your browser to inspect all the CSS rules, to see where it's coming from? Maybe that website builder put an `!important` somewhere or is adding CSS through JavaScript, which would override any style sheets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Why your code is not working

Although your code logically is correct, you must take into account how CSS works, especially in how it sets styles. If you have a certain element with that has `color: blaa;`, then it will always set that after what it inherits. So when you use `body {blaa...}`, you will only be able to see the results if nothing else later on overrides that. Here is a diagram to show you this:

For an element with the ID of "ID" in something like: body > nav > #ID then the styles will be applied like this:

1. BODY STYLES:
2. NAV STYLES
3. #ID STYLES or .CLASS STYLES
4. * STYLES

In this, if you specify a rule like: `body { color:red }`, and then `#id { color:blue }` then the color will be blue as it is the latest out of the 2 in the list above.

## Why dooj sahu's answer has been down voted

This is because `!important` is not the best to use when there are other ways to go without it.

## The way to do it

The best way to solve your problem is by using;

```css
* {
  color: #b6b6b6
}
```

Comment: OK so this makes sense.  However I cannot get the text color to change no matter what I do. I literally replaced every instance of the old color hex code with the new color code in the CSS file and the live website still shows the old color.  Also, I tried using !important in the body styles as suggested and that didn't work either.  I did find this code in the head [<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">]  I'm not sure what that is but I removed it and it made no difference.

Comment: Are you sure you have saved it and uploaded it o the live server

Comment: Yes.  I use Dreamweaver to upload ftp and the css file is present on my website host server.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome 84.0.4147.105

Comment: OK so I just tried it in Firefox and Edge and it works correctly in those browsers.  Just not in Chrome.  strange.

Comment: And....I cleared the cache in Chrome and now it's working.

Comment: Try. Right-click:inspecting

Comment: @Maximilian Ast, Thanks for the edit, I am not the best at markdown

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
  color: #b6b6b6
}
```

If you are begineer, i add a precision:

"*" target entire website, you can change background-color for example and whatever property you want.

Answer (score -3):

Simply use `!important`:

```
    body {
        font-family: Lato;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #b6b6b6 !important;
        background-color: #750204;
    }
```

Comment: Although it would work, it is not really best practice.